# How to use windows function to write sql where value of current row depends on previos row

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have table with values

```
val1
1
2
3
4
```

I want following as output

```
1.00
2.50
4.25
6.12
```

Each value in a table is computed as val1+0.5*val1(from Previous row)
so for .eg.
row with 2 ---> output is computed as 2+0.5*1.00= 2.50
row with 3 ---> output is computed as 3+0.5*2.50 = 4.25

When I use following sql windows function

```
SELECT *
   ,val1+SUM(0.50*val1) OVER (ORDER BY val1 ROWS between 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) AS r
FROM #a1
```

I get output as

```
1.00
2.500
4.000
5.500
```

Comment: tag the database being used? like SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres etc.

Comment: The problem is you are wanting it to use the first table only once and then use the result of the math and ignore the actual table, you want it to use the result set. val1 is 2 not 2.5 on the table.\

Comment: yes - It is like running total where total for current row is Total from previous Row + current row value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a recursive cte.

```
with rownums as (select val,row_number() over(order by val) as rnum 
                 from tbl)
/* This is the recursive cte */
,cte as (select val,rnum,cast(val as float) as new_val from rownums where rnum=1
         union all
         select r.val,r.rnum,r.val+0.5*c.new_val
         from cte c
         join rownums r on c.rnum=r.rnum-1
        )
/* End Recursive cte */
select val,new_val
from cte
```

**[Sample Demo](http://rextester.com/XXDWY23802)**

Answer (score 3):

This is called exponential averaging.  You can do it with some sort of power function, say it is called `power()` (this might differ among databases).

The following will work -- but I'm not sure about what happens if the sequences get long.  Note that this has an `id` column to specify the ordering:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, 1 as val union all
      select 2, 2 union all select 3, 3 union all select 4, 4
     )
select t.*,
       ( sum(p_seqnum * val) over (order by id) ) / p_seqnum
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id desc) as seqnum,
             power(cast(0.5 as float), row_number() over (order by id desc)) as p_seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler) for Postgres.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/2657) is a SQL Fiddle for SQL Server.

This works because exponential averaging is "memory-less".  If this were not true, you would need a recursive CTE, and that can be much more expensive.

Comment: Gordon, pure art